# Automatically switching connection string on database connection error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, database-connection, connection-string

I'm dealing with a C# application with a EntityFramework backbone using a DbContext.
The application has two choices: connect to a remote SQL server express or connect to a local SQL compact 4.0 database in case the network connection is not available.
When my application starts, a thread is checking if a connection to the remote database is possible. Otherwise it automatically needs to switch the connection string and provider in order to connect to the local database.
So far I was trying to deal with this issue by modifying the connection string section in app.config and forcing the application to refresh the section, after saving the configuration. This approach is not the best since I need to have access rights to write into the app.config file.
Could you suggest a better approach?

Comment: Where are you storing the two connection strings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) constructor accepts either the name of the connection string, or the actual connection string you want to choose.

What you could do, is test your initial connection string - maybe with a quick ado connection or something simple, and then if it connects use it, otherwise connect using your other one.

Some pseudocode:

```
        YourDbContext YourContext;
        if (TestConnection())
        {
            YourContext = new YourDbContext("ConnectionString1");
        }
        else
        {
            YourContext = new YourDbContext("ConnectionString2");
        }
```

Comment: How do I set the database provider? I need to switch between an SQL server express and a SQL compact 4.0

Comment: The reference to the "ConnectionString" can be the name of a connection string in your app.config.  If possible, I'd just have both connection strings in there, and reference them by name.

Comment: I cannot have the strings in the app.config, I need to specify them programmatically. I tried to insert in the string the databaseName and got back an exception "keyword not valid: database". How could this be possibly solved?

Comment: I think you created a new question about this - but try changing the DefaultConnectionFactory prior to instantiating your model: Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");

Comment: Yes, I did, for clarification purposes for other users. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the management of connection strings in a class, make that class a singleton, and use it to obtain the active connection string, like this:

```
public delegate void ConnectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

class ConnStringManager {
    static public ConnStringManager Instance {get;private set;}
    static {
        Instance = new ConnStringManager();
    }
    public event ConnectionChangedEventHandler Changed;
    private readonly string localConn;
    private readonly string remoteConn;
    public string ConnectionString {get; private set;}
    private ConnStringManager() {
        localConn = ... // Get local connection string from the config
        remoteConn = ... // Get remote connection string from the config
        TestAndSetConnectionString();
    }
    public void TestAndSetConnectionString() {
        bool canUseRemote = true;
        if (...) {
             // Do some testing to see if remote DB is accessible
        }
        // Switch the connection string
        var nextString = canUseRemote ? remoteConn : localConn;
        bool changed = nextString != ConnectionString;
        ConnectionString = nextString;
        if (changed && Changed != null) {
             Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This design approach seems clean and effective but, beside the wrapping of the whole into a class, my problem is another: how to tell to entityframework engine that I switched the connection string and the DB provider?

Comment: @Francesco You can add a `Changed` event to let users see changes. See the edits for details.